# Telerik Report auto centre table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

I have created one report which hides some of the columns of table at end when some criteria don't match. For example, there are total 7 columns and I am hiding 2 columns when criteria don't match. This leads to so much empty space at right side as table don't centre automatically.

I have tried `VerticalAlign = Middle` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after all efforts I didn't find exact solution but found one alternative.

I have applied `Anchoring = Left, Right` on table and that helps me to make my table looks better.

What it actually does is, it keeps width as it was specified and based on no. of columns, columns width either shrink or grows.